# Access Objects Created By Another VB Script

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has textboxes where the user can type text to filter results. The textboxes are created dynamically by an extender below:
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Namespace ControlExtenders
        Partial Public Class GridView : Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView

```
    ' METHOD:: OnLoad
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        Me.SetPageSize()
    End Sub
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub InitializeRow(ByVal row As GridViewRow, ByVal fields As DataControlField())
        MyBase.InitializeRow(row, fields)
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        InitializeHeaderRow(row, fields)
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Overridable Sub InitializeHeaderRow(ByVal row As GridViewRow, ByVal fields As DataControlField())
        ' AddGlyph(Me, row)
        AddFilters(row, fields)
    End Sub
    Protected Overridable Sub AddFilters(ByVal headerRow As GridViewRow, ByVal fields As DataControlField())
        For i As Integer = 0 To Columns.Count - 1
        If Not Columns(i).SortExpression = [String].Empty Then
            AddFilter(i, headerRow.Cells(i), fields(i))
        End If
        Next
    End Sub
    Dim m_txtFilter As New Hashtable
    Dim m_ddlFilter As New Hashtable

    Protected Overridable Sub AddFilter(ByVal columnIndex As Integer, ByVal headerCell As TableCell, ByVal field As DataControlField)
        If headerCell.Controls.Count = 0 Then
        Dim ltlHeaderText As New LiteralControl(headerCell.Text)
        headerCell.Controls.Add(ltlHeaderText)
        End If
        Dim ltlBreak As New LiteralControl("</br>")
        headerCell.Controls.Add(ltlBreak)
        Dim txtFilter As TextBox = Nothing
        If m_txtFilter.Contains(columnIndex) Then
        txtFilter = DirectCast(m_txtFilter(columnIndex), TextBox)
        Else
        txtFilter = New TextBox()
        txtFilter.ID = (ID & "_txtFilter") + columnIndex.ToString()

        'If field.ItemStyle.Width.Value <> 0.0R Then
        '    txtFilter.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, Convert.ToString(field.ItemStyle.Width.Value) & "px")
        'ElseIf field.HeaderStyle.Width.Value <> 0.0R Then
        '    txtFilter.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, Convert.ToString(field.HeaderStyle.Width.Value) & "px")
        'Else
        'End If
        m_txtFilter(columnIndex) = txtFilter
        AddHandler txtFilter.TextChanged, AddressOf Me.HandleFilterCommand
        Dim js As String
        js = "javascript:" & Page.GetPostBackEventReference(Me, "@@@@@buttonPostBack") & ";"
        txtFilter.Attributes.Add("onchange", js)

        End If

        headerCell.Controls.Add(txtFilter)


    End Sub
    Private Sub HandleFilterCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'this is required to make sure that unsetting of filter is also handled 
        Me.RequiresDataBinding = True
        ' Dim filterArgs As New FilterCommandEventArgs()
        'filterArgs.FilterExpression = GetFilterCommand()
        Dim filterString = GetFilterCommand()
        'Me.OnFilterCommand(filterArgs)
    End Sub
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnPreRender(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim filterCommand As String = GetFilterCommand()
        If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(filterCommand) = False Then
        ApplyFilterCommand(filterCommand)
        End If
        MyBase.OnPreRender(e)
    End Sub
    Public Function IsBoundColumn(ByVal objColumn As DataControlField) As Boolean
        If Not objColumn.SortExpression = String.Empty Then
        Return True
        End If
    End Function
    Protected Overridable Function GetFilterCommand() As String
        ' Return ""
        Dim filterCommand As String = ""
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < Me.Columns.Count
        If IsBoundColumn(Me.Columns(i)) Then
            If Me.HeaderRow Is Nothing Then
            i = i + 1

            Continue While
            End If
            Dim headerCell As DataControlFieldHeaderCell = DirectCast(Me.HeaderRow.Cells(i), DataControlFieldHeaderCell)
            Dim txtFilter As TextBox = DirectCast(m_txtFilter(i), TextBox)

            Dim aColumn As DataControlField
            'If Not (TypeOf Me.Columns(i) Is BoundField) Then
            '    i = i + 1
            '    Continue While
            'End If
            aColumn = DirectCast(Me.Columns(i), DataControlField)
            If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilter.Text) Then
            i = i + 1

            Continue While
            End If
            Dim TextValue As String = txtFilter.Text
            TextValue = TextValue.Replace("'", "''")

            If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(filterCommand) Then
            '                       Convert(TimespanColumn, 'System.String'
            filterCommand = "Convert(" & aColumn.SortExpression + "," + Chr(39) + "System.String" + Chr(39) + ") like " + Chr(39) + "%" + TextValue + "%" + Chr(39)
            Else
            filterCommand += " AND " + "Convert(" & aColumn.SortExpression + "," + Chr(39) + "System.String" + Chr(39) + ") like " + Chr(39) + "%" + TextValue + "%" + Chr(39)
            End If
        End If
        System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)
        End While
        Return filterCommand
    End Function
    Protected Overridable Sub ApplyFilterCommand(ByVal filterCommand As String)
        Dim dsv As DataSourceView = Me.GetData()
        Dim objDataSourceView As ObjectDataSourceView = dsv
        objDataSourceView.FilterExpression = filterCommand
        Me.DataBind()

        If Me.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        objDataSourceView.FilterExpression = ""
        Me.ShowNotFoundMessage()
        Me.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShowNotFoundMessage()
        Dim strMessage As String = "No records found for this specified search specification."
        Dim strScript As String = "alert('" & strMessage & "'); "
        If (Not Me.Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientScript")) Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "clientScript", strScript, True)
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub SetPageSize()
        'Skip hardcoded page size for role permission
        If Me.PageSize <> 500 And Me.PageSize <> 25 Then
        Me.PageSize = DBUtilities.GetPageSize
        End If
    End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

My question is, how do I access the values of the created textboxes in the calling page's code? I've tried the following but none of them work:

```
Label.Text = GridView1.FindControl("txtFilter3")
```

or

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(0)
Label.Text = row.Cells(2).Text
```

or

```
Label.Text = C_C_C_CtlAccountProjectList1_GridView1_GridView1_txtFilter3
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing them through javascript?

Comment: No I haven't - would I do that in .ascx file or the .ascx.vb file? Do you have an example of what that would look like? The javascript functions I've written require an ID argument, which I'm not able to get right now.

Comment: It would be in the .ascx file using <script> tags. Maybe I am missing something. How come you are not able to get an ID?

Comment: To be honest, that's what I don't understand either (I inherited this code). My guess is that the GridView.vb extender is called AFTER the .ascx page is called?

Comment: Hmm I'm not too sure. So to get this straight; you do not create the textboxes in your code? They are auto generated by a script that you do not have access to?

Comment: The text boxes are generated by the first block of code, which overloads the default GridView behavior and creates textboxes. So from my understanding: Page.ascx creates gridview (no textboxes) -> GridView.vb adds textboxes -> Page.ascx.vb can't access textboxes.

Comment: hmm so I would try to see if they can be accessed by javascript. Try something like this:

`document.getElementById('txtFilter').value`

Comment: Argh, stupidity on my part. The textbox is given an ID with this line of code: txtFilter.ID = (ID & "_txtFilter") + columnIndex.ToString().
That means to access it I need to findControl("GridView1_txtFilter3") instead of findControl("txtFilter3")
@ChaseErnst - thanks for your help - it was while I was trying to implement your suggestion that I saw the issue.

Comment: Ah, well if you solved your problem then submit it as an answer and mark it as correct!